# Security Group Rules 'undefined' when connecting EFS to EC2

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to connect an EFS volume to an EC2 instance using the AWS CDK in Python.

Create my instance

```
instance = ec2.CfnInstance(stack, cdk.Stack.of(stack).stack_name,
    key_name="key-name",
    subnet_id="subnet-123",
    security_group_ids=["sg-123"],
    iam_instance_profile="profile-name",
    instance_type="t3.medium",
    image_id="ami-08d4ac5b634553e16",
    block_device_mappings=[ec2.CfnInstance.BlockDeviceMappingProperty(
        device_name="/dev/sda1",
        ebs=ec2.CfnInstance.EbsProperty(
            delete_on_termination=True,
            volume_size=12,
            volume_type="gp3"
        )
    )],
    user_data=cdk.Fn.base64(init_script.render()),
    tags=
    [cdk.CfnTag(
        key="Name",
        value=cdk.Stack.of(stack).stack_name
    )])
```

Create my EFS file system

```
fs = efs.FileSystem(self, "fs:{}".format(cdk.Stack.of(self).stack_name),
    vpc=ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "vpc-123"),
    encrypted=True,
    file_system_name="fs:{}".format(cdk.Stack.of(self).stack_name),
    performance_mode=efs.PerformanceMode.GENERAL_PURPOSE,
    security_group=ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, "sg", "sg-123")
)
```

Connect fs to the instance

```
fs.connections.allow_default_port_from(instance)
```

Get the following error on the `fs.connections.allow_default_port_from(instance)` line

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_securityGroupRules')
```

The documentation/guide that I've been following is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_efs/README.html#mounting-the-file-system-using-user-data). In attempting to figure this out, I can confirm that my security group is part of the connections object. In the AWS console I can confirm that there are in fact security group rules attached to this security group. I know I'm missing something, I'm just confused at this point and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow_default_port_from` takes an argument of type `IConnectable`, like an `ec2.Instance`. It only works with higher-level L2 constructs. You're trying to pass a `ec2.CfnInstance` construct, which is not compatible.

Your options:

1. Use the L2 `ec2.Instance` construct, it is much more feature-rich and supports CDK abstractions such as this one
2. Create a `ec2.Connections` objects yourself, passing it the security group of your `CfnInstance`.

Comment: Thanks, I originally tried to use `ec2.Instance` but ran into some problems there, which resulted in me eventually using the `CfnInstance`.